# Php image sending on linux server

Tags: php, linux, bots, vk

I had a php bot, that can send pictures. Now i moved it from heroku to apache 2 on Rasberry pi 4.
It works good, but i can't send pictures at all. (on heroku i could).
Bot has access to folder, can save files from internet, create new files, but can't send them. What could be the problem?

I think problem not with the code, but i leave it here

```
    public function sendImage($id, $local_file_path)
    {
        $upload_url = $this->sendDocuments($id, 'photo')['upload_url'];
        $answer_vk = json_decode($this->sendFiles($upload_url, $local_file_path, 'photo'), true);
        $upload_file = $this->savePhoto($answer_vk['photo'], $answer_vk['server'], $answer_vk['hash']);
        $this->request('messages.send', array('attachment' => "photo" . $upload_file[0]['owner_id'] . "_" . $upload_file[0]['id'], 'peer_id' => $id));
        return 1;
    }
}
$img_dir=__DIR__ . "/img/";
$vk->sendImage($peer_id, $img_dir."Raid.jpg", "Raid.jpg");
```

Comment: Does Apache have rights to write into `__DIR__ . "/img/"`?

Comment: Well, what issue do you see in your http server's error log file? That certainly is the first thing you want to check...

Comment: Why `sendImage()` takes 2 arguments, but 3 are given ?

Comment: I can't remember, but it works on heroku. 
About rights - yes. And it even creates picture, but not sends it

Comment: @Syscall is right. This should raise an error, you're probably missing an argument. BTW, where's he definition of $photo variable? Could it possibly be the missing argument?

Comment: @Samy no logs at all, i searched for them. nope, As i say'd on other server it works great.

Comment: If this is the same code that was running on Heroku, then it should raise an error since you're supplying 3 arguments to a function that only takes 2. No programming language ever is that forgiving.

Comment: @samy I tryed with 2, but with 2 it does not work even on heroku

Comment: Could you post the content your apache access and error logs?

Comment: @Samy It's empty. (I mean no new logs at all last log was more than day ago) (both)

Comment: Could you use a try-catch statement on the function call statement? Please print the message returned by "catch" and edit it the question with the output.

Comment: Can you explain "can't send" more? That function is called `sendImage`, and inside it calls `sendDocuments` and `sendFiles`. I'm assuming one of the latter two are what your problem is. Have you turned PHP error reporting on fully and debugged those line-by-line? For instance, `sendDocuments` is required to return a key-array, does it? And `sendFiles` returns a string, have you inspected that string before turning it into JSON?